# How to retrieve a sub collection inside every object of a firebase collection in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm retrieving a collection of elements from firebase in a react app. I'm displaying them in a grid.

For each line of my grid, I want to display a list of elements that are presents in a subcollection of each document.

How can I achieve this?

Here is where I'm at:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
    const householdsRef = collection(db, "households");
    const queryRef = query(
    householdsRef,
    where("participantsIds", "array-contains", user!.uid)
    );
    const collectionRef = queryRef.withConverter(householdConverter);
    const [households, householdLoading, householdError, householdSnapshot] = useCollectionData<Household>(collectionRef);
    
    
    return (
        <TableContainer>
            <Table>
                <Thead>
                    <Tr>
                        <Th>Household</Th>
                        <Th>Owner</Th>
                        <Th>Invited people</Th>
                    </Tr>
                </Thead>
                <Tbody>
                    {households?.map((household)=> (
                        <Tr key={household.id>
                            <Td>{household.name}</Td>
                            <Td>{household.owner}</Td>
                            <Td>
                            <ul>
                                {// -------Here, how to retrieve elements of the sub collection of invitedUsers? -------}
                                {household.invitedUsers.map((invitedUser) => (
                                    <li key={invitedUser.id}>invitedUser.name</li>
                                ))}
                            </ul>
                            </Td>
                        </Tr>                   
                    )}
                    
                </Tbody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        );
    
}
```

I tried to add this to my converter:

```
const householdConverter: FirestoreDataConverter<Household> = {
  toFirestore(household: WithFieldValue<Household>): DocumentData {
    return {
      name: household.name,
      ownerId: household.ownerId,
      ownerName: household.ownerName,
      participants: household.participants,
      participantsIds: household.participantsIds,
      invitedUsers: household.invitedUsers,
    };
  },
  fromFirestore(
    snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot,
    options: SnapshotOptions
  ): Household {
    const data = snapshot.data(options);
    return {
      id: snapshot.id,
      name: data.name,
      ownerId: data.ownerId,
      ownerName: data.ownerName,
      participants: data.participants,
      participantsIds: data.participantsIds,
      invitedUsers: data.invitedUsers,
      ref: snapshot.ref,
    };
  },
};
export default householdConverter;
```

but invitedUsers stay undefined.

How can I retrieve the subcollection "invitedUsers" for each household?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? Please share your debugging information, including enough information that anyone can use to duplicate the unexpected behavior. Are you sure `invitedUsers` is actually a subcollection?  Or is it just an array type field within the document? Those are very different things - but we can't tell because we can't see your database.

Comment: Hi, invitedUsers stays undefined. I'm 100% sure that invitedUsers is a subcollection and not a map in the same object(this would work, but that doesn't allow me to set more specific access rules in firestore)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get subcollection data when querying for a document under which it is nested.  Each subcollection must be queried entirely separately (or a collection group query can be used to query all collections and subcollections with the same name).

You have to create a reference to the subcollection using its full path (you must know all of its path segments, including the nested document ID), then execute a query on it in the same way you would a top-level collection. e.g.

```
const ref = collection(collectionRef, documentId, subcollectionName)
query(ref)
```

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#collection_2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this something possible inside a react map function?

Comment: I don't know. Why don't you give your idea a try, then post another question with your debugging details if it doesn't work the way you expect?